# Calculate all the local automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

> The Kohn - Nirenberg domain $\Omega_{KN}$ defined by
>   $$\Omega_{KN}=\left\{(z,w)\in \Bbb C^2:\text{Re}\ w+|zw|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z|^2\text{Re}\ z^6<0\right\}$$

How to compute all the local automorphisms of $\partial \Omega_{KN}$?

================================================================

What I have tried:

- I change the variable as the following $\widetilde{w}=iw,\ w=x+iy,\ x,y \in \Bbb R$. Then $\text{Re}\ \widetilde{w}=\text{Re}\ (-y+ix)=-y=-\text{Im}\ {w}$. We consider $r$ be a local defining function:
  $$\begin{align*}
   r:\Bbb C^2 & \to \Bbb R \\ 
   (z,w)&\mapsto r(z,w)=\text{Re}\ w+|zw|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z|^2\text{Re}\ z^6
  \end{align*}$$

Thus, We have the equation of $\partial \Omega_{KN}=\{r=0\}$ in neighbourhood of $(0,0)$:
\begin{align*}
0 &=\text{Re}\ \widetilde{w}+|iz\widetilde{w}|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z|^2\text{Re}\ z^6 \\ 
 \Rightarrow \text{Im}w &= |z{w}|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z|^2\text{Re}\ z^6\\
\end{align*}

- By Martin Kolář, we have:
  $$P_{a}^{k,l}(z,\overline{z})=|z|^k+a|z|^{k-l}\text{Re}z^l$$

In case, we have $k=8,l=6,a=\dfrac{15}{7}$, and $\Omega_{KN}$ is a pseudoconvex.

=======================================

Now, I have stuck...when I try to compute all the local automorphisms! I think that we have $6$ local automorphisms. Because, we recall a **Theorem**:

> *The automorphism group of the Kohn - Nirenberg domain $\Omega_{KN}$ is equal to the set* $\{\Pi^n:\ n=1, \ldots,6\}$, *where* $\Pi(z,w)=(e^\frac{i\pi}{3}z,w).$

But How to compute all the local automorphisms of $\partial \Omega_{KN}$?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!